# Reference for mathematical writing piece by Mac Lane

Tags: reference-request

Hello,
I have been told that Mac Lane wrote a article on guidelines for writing(publishing) mathematics, and that it came out in one of the AMS publications(monthly, bulletin,..). I have run searches and have not been able to find any reference. Is anyone aware of this article, and happen to know where it may be found?
Thank you

Comment: Could you be thinking of "How to Write Mathematics" by Halmos? This was originally published in L'Enseignement Math. (1970) and then reprinted (along with some similar essays by others) by the AMS in 1973. http://www.math.uga.edu/~azoff/courses/halmos.pdf

Comment: in the same spirit, you might want to check out

http://tex.loria.fr/typographie/mathwriting.pdf

Comment: @DaveLRenfro, It seems that this is indeed what I was after. My mistake on the author. Thanks for the link!